# How can i set document serially in firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want when a new user registers then in the userProfile collection there I should be able to set a unique id to each user like
P-_____

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using firebase authentication then you can do the following

```
final String Uid =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc("P-"+Uid).set(data);
```

Alternatively, if you are not using FirebaseAuth then you can do the following

```
final String Uid =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
firestore.collection(collectionPath).doc("P-"+getRandomString(10)).set(data);  //random string with 10 charecter
```

Code to generate a random string

```
const _chars = 'AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890';
Random _rnd = Random();

String getRandomString(int length) => String.fromCharCodes(Iterable.generate(
    length, (_) => _chars.codeUnitAt(_rnd.nextInt(_chars.length))));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `add` method adds the new document to your collection with a unique auto-generated ID. If you'd like to specify your own ID, call the `set` method on a DocumentReference instead:

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> addUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .set({
      'full_name': "Mary Jane",
      'age': 18
    })
    .then((value) => print("User Added"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}
```

Calling `set` with a id that already exists on the collection will replace all the document data.